# OpenCL max_work_item_sizes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencl, pyopencl

I am having trouble understanding what the work item constraints mean. I am using `pyopencl` and looking at the `max_work_item_sizes` it gives what I assumed was the max number of global work threads for each dimension.

```py
import pyopencl as cl
import numpy as np

ctx = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)

queue.device.max_work_item_sizes # [1024, 1024, 64]
```

I could simulate the `np.arange` function by the following:

```
prg = cl.Program(ctx, """
__kernel void arange(__global int *res_g)
{
  int gid = get_global_id(0);
  res_g[gid] = gid;
}
""").build()

res_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, cl.mem_flags.READ_WRITE, 4 * 4096)
prg.arange(queue, [4096], None, res_g)

# transfer back to cpu
res_np = np.empty(4096).astype(np.int32)
cl.enqueue_copy(queue, res_np, res_g)

assert (res_np == np.arange(4096)).all() # this is true
```

How is it possible to specify more than 1024 work items for the first dimension? What does the `max_work_item_sizes` mean?

Another question related to this is if it is beneficial to use as many work dimensions as possible? As I understand it possible to use 3 dimensions at most. A way of simulating `np.arange` by using 2 work item dimensions could be done by the following:

```
prg = cl.Program(ctx, """
__kernel void arange(__global int *res_g)
{
  int gid = get_global_id(0) * get_global_id(1);
  barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
  res_g[gid] = gid;
}
""").build()

res_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, cl.mem_flags.READ_WRITE, 4 * 4096)
prg.arange(queue, [64, 64], [1,1], res_g)

# transfer back to cpu
res_np = np.empty(4096).astype(np.int32)
cl.enqueue_copy(queue, res_np, res_g)

assert (res_np == np.arange(4096)).all()
```

*For some reason the assertion is not always true*

But my question is, when processing a large array, is it better to make use of all 3 `work_item_dimensions`? Or is it better to treat the array as a 1d contiguous array and only use `get_global_id(0)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is it possible to specify more than 1024 work items for the first
> dimension? What does the max_work_item_sizes mean?

`max_work_item_sizes` returns maximum number of work items per work group in each dimension.

By passing `None` as third argument:

```
prg.arange(queue, [4096], None, res_g)
                          ^^^^
```

implementation is being asked to select the best work group size. Checking work group size can be done this way, for example:

```
res_g[gid] = get_local_size(0);
```

In my system `max_work_item_sizes=[4096, 4096, 4096]` and the value returned by `get_local_size(0)` is 1024 which means that implementation decided that work group size is 1024 items and 4096 / 1024 gives us 4 work groups scheduled.

Specifying work group size, for example to 256 work items:

```
prg.arange(queue, [4096], [256], res_g)
```

will schedule 4 times more work groups.

> Another question related to this is if it is beneficial to use as many
> work dimensions as possible? As I understand it possible to use 3
> dimensions at most.

and

> But my question is, when processing a large array, is it better to
> make use of all 3 work_item_dimensions? Or is it better to treat the
> array as a 1d contiguous array and only use get_global_id(0)?

From my experience there is no difference whether it's one or more dimensions being used. So you do as it's more convenient for you.

> For some reason the assertion is not always true

That's because there is a bug in your code. Calculating index should be:

```
int gid = get_global_id(0) * get_global_size(0) + get_global_id(1);
```

Comment: Thanks. So looking at the [documentation](https://documen.tician.de/pyopencl/runtime_program.html#pyopencl.Kernel.__call__), ```max_work_item_sizes``` is specifying the maximum ```local_size``` (or workgroup size) for each corresponding dimension? Does the ```global_size``` have any limit if I set ```local_size=None```?

Comment: Yes `max_work_item_sizes` is the max number of work items in the work group which can be queried inside the kernel by `get_local_size(dimension)`; Specifying `local_size` or not does not have any influence on `global_size` value. Just the restriction is that `global_size` has to be the number divisible by `local_size`. I haven't hear of any limit for global_size but it may be limited by the data type being used for it or by resources needed to process so large kernel (for example more data need to be passed to the kernel which is limited by global memory size).

Comment: I have another question: When doing simple operations on the gpu like multiplication and addition, will it be better to specify the ```local_size``` to be 1 and not launch any unnecessary threads (if that makes sense)? Since doing *addition* we only ever need to use ```get_global_id(0)``` if both arrays (operands) are of the same size.

Comment: Specifying local_size=1 will likely hurt the performance. The minimum local_size should rather be 32 or 64 for 1D (for 2D multiplication of 2 dimensions greater or equal). But if the algorithm uses only global_id/size then usually is better to let implementation to decide the best local size.